# How to establish inter-rater reliability as a sole PhD researcher

Tags: research-process, independent-researcher, methodology, social-science

I'm doing a PhD in the social sciences and want to use an observational method to analyse audio recordings of social work conversations. I will be using an established behavioural coding manual ([the Motivational Interviewing Skills Code 2.5](https://casaa.unm.edu/download/misc25.pdf)) to assign behavioural codes to the interaction. The problem I have is that I need a way of demonstrating that my coding is reliable. Typically, on studies I have worked on in the past, there would be a small sample of recordings that would be re-coded by at least one other person to establish inter-rater reliability. As a sole researcher, I cannot do this.

Is there a way around this issue?

Comment: Please explain why you are a sole researcher. You do have an advisor, don't you?

Comment: It seems inherently impossible to say anything about inter-rater reliability when you only have data from one rater.  So, I would say you should start looking into ways to get another rater.  Look for a collaborator, or funding to hire someone.  Or else accept that you won't be able to establish this.

Comment: There are small sample statistical measures that might be applied: https://measuringu.com/small-n/

Answer (score 1):

The measurement of an inter-rater reliability premises multiple raters.

I therefore see three possible solutions for you to thematize this issue:

- First, aim to get another rater. The best approach for you would be to apply for and obtain funding in order to hire one. I say that this is the 'best' approach because it would demonstrate (a) your ability to get grants for research purposes and (b) your accuracy and honesty with regards to this methodical task. But if that does not work, there are other options; perhaps you can ask among your friends and colleagues to volunteer their time for you (this is what I once did, and my wife volunteered for a small rating task). Or perhaps your supervisor can arrange a student or research assistant for this task.
- Second, you can disclose that you were unable to obtain a second rater (due to resource constraints). Your paper's discussion section would highlight this as a limitation of your research, and it would identify the measurement of your approach's reliability as a gap to be closed through 'future research'. This is not shameful; in every scientific publication there should be a discussion section that identifies limitations and further research paths anyway.
- Third, you could split yourself into two 'raters' by assuming that you were rater number one at time *t1* and rater number two at time *t2*. However, I have never seen this approach, and it is merely a bold speculation from my side; I am sure that this would be accompanied with grave methodical concerns. Thus, I should also add: Don't follow this advice, just to be sure.

Comment: If there is a lot of data, the second rater might only rate a sample, reducing the cost.